# Creating new git repository as a replacement of existing git repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have three existing git repos **RepoA**, **RepoB** and **RepoC**.

**RepoA** is being used as a **submodule** within **RepoC**.

What I am looking for is to use *RepoB* as *RepoA* now onwards, and mark *RepoA* as obsolete. To avoid updating .gitmodule file in each dependent repositories, I simply want to get rid of *RepoA* and rename *RepoB* as *RepoA*.

#### To summarize, existing state is

*RepoA* - with latest develop branch having commit ID 12345

*RepoC* -> submodule  -> *Repo A* (12345)

*RepoB* - with latest develop branch having commit ID 98765

#### What I want is,

*RepoA* - deleted or renamed to "obsolete"

*RepoB* - renamed to *RepoA* (so that .gitmodule files in other repos stays valid)

*RepoC*
-> submodule  -> *RepoA* (renamed *RepoB*) (98765)

I tried to do some experiments, but not sure what steps shall I follow to be safe without too much mess for *RepoC* users.

Great thanks for your help!

Comment: bear in mind that git commits reference submodule commits by their exact IDs. So replacing one repository with another may lead to broken commits in RepoC.

Answer (score 0):

I would move Repo A's code into a subdirectory of the root, commit / document this movement, then delete the folder.  I would then merge Repo B into Repo A at the root directory.  That way you preserve Repo A's code history in a specific location.

Destroying code history is generally not preferable.  This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but what you're asking to do is going to make your source code's genealogy confusing and completely obliterate the history of Repo A.

Comment: Yes, whole point is to retain histories. Actually RepoA was just a copy of RepoB (original repo with genealogy maintained) but without histories, since it was created as copying the source code (rather than formal merging) . We then realized this, and hence want to switch to RepoB, but obviously with changed name (RepoA).

Comment: I would look into it as a merging of histories rather than a full repository delete-and-replace.  This article gives a series of steps involving creating a remote repository, two subdirectories, and a merge between the two.  I think that would cover what you're trying to do.  https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/